# How to redirect in codeIgniter with multiple variables

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, redirect, parameters

I have 3 variables `$a,$b,$c`

```
$a=2015/15/12, 
$b=12,
$C=ok,
```

And am trying pass that value in the following way

```
redirect('mycontroller/myfunction/'.$a.'/'. $b.'/'. $c.'refresh')
```

and its not working properly. So how can i pass this variables  through redirect 
??

Comment: How is it not working properly? Please, add what is happening and what you are expecting to happen. For example I cannot determine if the problem is because the `$a` variable is not encoded, or you explicitly want to treat the slashes in `$a` as path separators.

Answer (score 1):

You should seperate the second argument with a comma, thus it must be a string either one of auto, location or refresh. See the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) for further information.

```
redirect('mycontroller/myfunction/'.urlencode($a).'/'. $b.'/'. $c, 'refresh');
```

Then within your view you can access them like below:

```
$a = urldecode($this->uri->segment(3));
$b = $this->uri->segment(4);
$c = $this->uri->segment(5);
```

Comment: updated my answer, for slashes, just use `urlencode` for redirect and `urldecode` for accessing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you missed comma in redirect use below code

> redirect('mycontroller/myfunction/'.$a.'/'. $b.'/'. $c ,'refresh')